# WebBrowser Display partial website

Tags: c#

I'm displaying a website in a C# WebBrowser. But I would like to display only the search part not the whole website so it won't bo so big on the screen. This is the website http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/ and I would like to display only the Busca CEP - Endereço Box. Any ideas of how I can do this? I tryed to use htmlagilitypack but it has very little documentation and I couldn't understand it.

Comment: The proper way would be to make ur own searchbox (TextBox) and just send a post request to the website in the same way the site does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebBrowser control isn't really designed for what you're asking. You probably could go through all the page elements and remove anything that isn't part of the search box, but that's a lot of work for very little value.

However, there's a bright side. As mentioned in a comment, you should be able to POST directly to the search page. Use a program like Fiddler to find out what form values are being passed to the server with the request. Then you can re-create that request from your own application (using a WebClient or HttpClient). The result will be HTML, which you can display in your WebBrowser by setting the returned HTML to the WebBrowser's `DocumentText` property.